# .NET Core: Microsoft's strategy of extension methods

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm currently toying around with EF7, .NET Core, and so on. With .NET Core, it seems Microsoft's strategy is modularity, open communication, and an composition-based strategy.

The last point bothers me, since this seems to be a step back. An example: I tested out the new EF7 in combination with LocalDB, so I could simply ship the MDF with 3-4 Tables in my WPF-Application.

To do so, I needed a strategy to update the MDF for each user to assure the Database always has the same structure. I ended up using the appropriate Extension method:

```
    internal BoerseDownloaderDbContext Create()
    {
        var result = _unityContainer.Resolve<BoerseDownloaderDbContext>();
        result.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216983/update-database-after-model-changes-entity-framework-7
        result.Database.Migrate();

        return result;
    }
```

Now what bothers me: not only does such stuff hurt the Law of Demeter, but Extension-Methods are really painful to work with, since IntelliSense doesn't recognize them in the appropriate Namespace. Since I abstracted the DbContext, I didn't have the `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` Namespace in my Class, so there is no way I could ever know this Method exists. As usual, Stack Overflow gave me a hint, but it seems to really hinder the productivity, since I can never be sure if something exists or if I have to implement it myself.

It seems like this will get worse, so if we look at this video:
https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/A-Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10/08
At around 21:40, it shows clearly this is the strategy Microsoft is going for.

Is there anything I'm missing or is it just the fact that Extension Methods aren't very well integrated, an issue we will have to live with?

Comment: Something tells me you're not using ReSharper ;)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Not all of us get to have it as a luxury!

Comment: .NET Core is still under heavy development, and so is EF.Core. There's nothing you "need to live with". If this issue bothers you, [why not report it](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues)?

Comment: I don't think this is a library issue. It is somewhere between language (discovery rules for extension methods) and IDE (automated import helper without usage of tools like Re-Sharper). I think the language should at least support discovery of extension methods within the defining namespace of the extended type, regardless of the code files using directives.

Comment: @grek40 then you should report to Roslyn repo as IntelliSense of VS is powered by it.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I Have ReSharper on my Work-PC, but how does ReSharper support this?

Comment: @MatthiasMüller I missed the .NET Core part - R# lists extension methods in its autocompletion box, but I don't know how good their .NET Core support is.